# How can I configure Android so that the phone rings when I receive a phone call while in "do not disturb" mode?

Tags: notifications, calls, do-not-disturb, google-pixel-6

I tried to check allow all notifications:

[image]

However, after saving it, it gets unchecked again. It works fine for other applications.

How can I configure Android so that the phone rings when I receive a phone call while in "do not disturb" mode?

I use a Google Pixel 6.

Comment: On Pixel 3a Android 12, in the DnD settings, there's a setting for interrupts, and one of them is "People". Inside it, there's "Calls" with "Anyone" as an option. Does that work?

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks, perfect, still there in pixel 6. Can you post your comment as an answer? I can add the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andrew T.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) [commented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247055/how-can-i-configure-android-so-that-the-phone-rings-when-i-receive-a-phone-call#comment331243_247055), go to the `Do No Disturb` settings and change the people option:

[image]

Then call option:

[image]

Then one can select who may disturb:

[image]